# Is this some type of convergence of stochastic processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I have learned that there are several types of convergence of random variables and they are related somehow, but not yet for stochastic processes. I was wondering if the following is some type of convergence for stochastic processes $\Omega \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ with probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathrm{E}_\mathrm{P} \left(\int_{[0,T]} |f_n(\omega,t) - f(\omega,t)|^2 dt \right) = 0
$$

I encountered this in the definition of Ito integral, but didn't find more  about this type of convergence among others. I am also hoping to know relations between different convergence types and their connections to convergence types of random variables. Thanks and regards!

Comment: As far as I know the above is just the $L^2(dP,dt)$ convergence. Other type of convergence used for constructing stochastic integrals is for example [ucp convergence](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/u-c-p-convergence/). [Protter](http://books.google.de/books/about/Stochastic_integration_and_differential.html?hl=de&id=mJkFuqwr5xgC) is a good reference on that.

Comment: Hi there is also the (Emery's) Semi-martingale topology that induce a metric, and the Skorokhod topology over càdlàg process that has also a metric space structure. Regards